# CTRL +F Logic in java

Tags: java

I want to search the specific word in the text file and store that word in the array list. I have done like this but it gives output like word exist in the text file or not. I want to store that text in the array list

```
double count = 0, countBuffer = 0, countLine = 0;
String lineNumber = "";
String filePath = "D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt";
BufferedReader br;
String inputSearch = "Facture";
String line = "";

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            countLine++;
            //System.out.println(line);
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.equals(inputSearch)) {
                    count++;
                    countBuffer++;
                }
            }

            if (countBuffer > 0) {
                countBuffer = 0;
                lineNumber += countLine + ",";
            }

        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Define a String ArrayList, when (word.equals(inputSearch)), add the word into the ArrayList by ArrayLIst.add(word)

Comment: sorry i can't able to understand can you edit in the code ???

Answer (score 1):

```
double count = 0, countBuffer = 0, countLine = 0;
String lineNumber = "";
String filePath = "D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt";
BufferedReader br;
String inputSearch = "Facture";
String line = "";
List<String> searchedWords = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            countLine++;
            //System.out.println(line);
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.equals(inputSearch)) {
                    count++;
                    countBuffer++;
                    if(!searchedWords.contains(word)){
                        searchedWords.add(word);
                    }

                }
            }
            if (countBuffer > 0) {
                countBuffer = 0;
                lineNumber += countLine + ",";
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Words that you have searched and found:");
for(String word : searchedWords){
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

You will have an arraylist `searchedWords` which will keep track of the searched words, you will notice that the if statement will not allow duplicates in the arraylist, so if you want to allow duplicates just remove the `if(!searchedWords.contains(word))` and just write `searchedWords.add(word);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a String ArrayList with your other declarations using:

`ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();`

Then when you find a word that matches, add it to the ArrayList using:

```
matches.add(word);
```

Edit:

```
double count = 0, countBuffer = 0, countLine = 0;
String lineNumber = "";
String filePath = "D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt";
BufferedReader br;
String inputSearch = "Facture";
String line = "";
ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            countLine++;
            //System.out.println(line);
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.equals(inputSearch)) {
                    count++;
                    countBuffer++;
                    matches.add(word);
                }
            }

            if (countBuffer > 0) {
                countBuffer = 0;
                lineNumber += countLine + ",";
            }

        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```